# One-time pad encryption using letter shifting

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

This program asks the user to input a List of words. It then returns a list of encrypted words, and a second list which specifies the numerical shifts used to encrypt those words. The idea was obtained from https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/crypt/v/one-time-pad

```
import random

def rotate_letter(letter, number):
    if letter == ' ':
        return letter
    if letter.islower():
        start = ord('a')
    elif not letter.islower():
        start = ord('A')

    normal_shift = ord(letter) - start
    new_letter = start + (normal_shift + number) % 26
    return chr(new_letter)

def avoid(letter):
    avoid = ' ,!?¿,*+-%/@1234567890'
    for i in avoid:
        if i == letter:
            return False
    return True

def rotate_word(word):
    new_word = ''
    random_series = []
    for letter in word:
        if avoid(letter):
            random_number = random.randint(1,26)
            new_letter = rotate_letter(letter, random_number)
            new_word += new_letter
            random_series.append(random_number)
        else:
            new_word += letter
    return (new_word, random_series)

def shift(words):
    index = 0
    encrypted_words = []
    random_shifts = []
    while index < len(words):
        (new_word, random_series) = rotate_word(words[index])
        encrypted_words.append(new_word)
        random_shifts.append(random_series)
        index += 1
    return (encrypted_words, random_shifts)

def get_input():
    words = []
    while True:
        user = (input('Input words to encrypt. Done when ready \n' ))
        if user == 'Done' or user == 'done':
            return words
        words.append(user)

def start():
    words = get_input()
    encrypted_words = []
    random_shifts = []
    (encrypted_words, random_shifts) = shift(words)
    print('UNENCRYPTED WORDS', words)
    print('ENCRYPTED WORDS', encrypted_words)
    print('RANDOM SHIFTS', random_shifts)

start()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @Peilonrayz I would guess Python 3 because of his usage of `input`.

Answer (score 2):

Your function `avoid` is quite unnecessary and also confusing. I would expect `avoid('@')` to return `True`. When you store the letters as a global constant and as set, you should gain some speed (both because it does not have to be reconstructed again and again and because membership testing is very fast for a `set`. I replaced your function with `letter not in letters_avoid`.

Whenever you are doing string addition in Python, you are probably doing something wrong. This is because strings are immutable so for every addition a new string has to be created and the content of the strings to be added needs to be copied. This is quite slow. Rather, use a `list` to accumulate the letters of `new_word` and `str.join` them at the end.

When returning a `tuple`, the `()` are implicit. You can just write `return a, b`.

When iterating over `words`, you should just directly iterate over it, instead of its indices.

Using `str.lower` cuts down the double comparison `if user == 'Done' or user == 'done'` to `if user.lower() == 'done':`.

You should call your code with a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard to allow importing your functions from another script without executing the whole script.

**Final code:**

```
import random


letters_avoid = set(' ,!?¿,*+-%/@1234567890')


def rotate_letter(letter, number):
    if letter == ' ':
        return letter
    if letter.islower():
        start = ord('a')
    elif not letter.islower():
        start = ord('A')

    normal_shift = ord(letter) - start
    new_letter = start + (normal_shift + number) % 26
    return chr(new_letter)


def rotate_word(word):
    new_word = []
    random_series = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter not in letters_avoid:
            random_number = random.randint(1, 26)
            new_word.append(rotate_letter(letter, random_number))
            random_series.append(random_number)
        else:
            new_word.append(letter)
    return "".join(new_word), random_series


def shift(words):
    encrypted_words = []
    random_shifts = []
    for word in words:
        new_word, random_series = rotate_word(word)
        encrypted_words.append(new_word)
        random_shifts.append(random_series)
    return encrypted_words, random_shifts


def get_input():
    words = []
    while True:
        user = input('Input words to encrypt. Done when ready \n')
        if user.lower() == 'done':
            return words
        words.append(user)


def start():
    words = get_input()
    encrypted_words, random_shifts = shift(words)
    print('UNENCRYPTED WORDS', words)
    print('ENCRYPTED WORDS', encrypted_words)
    print('RANDOM SHIFTS', random_shifts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```